# Android GCM Rate Limit

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have seen few posts talking about GCM rate limits but still it is not clear to me. Let me ask question given a scenario:

```
    -----------------------------
   |                             |
   |          App Server         |
   |                             |
    -----------------------------
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
    -----------------------------
   |                             |
   |        GCM Connection       |
   |            Server           |
   |                             |
    -----------------------------
    /       |        \   ....    \
   /        |         \           \
  /         |          \           \
user #1     user #2     user #2   ... user #100000
```

Given the scenario above, i have following questions:

1. For downstream unicast messages, is there any rate limit/quota limit on how many & at what rate app server can send messages to users.
2. For upstream messages, is there any limit on how many messages/second GCM can push to App Server because there is single connection from App Server to GCM and all incoming (millions) will be pushed into same pipe. Any repercussion?